# Not able to download Cloudera

Tags: download, vmware, cloudera, cloudera-manager, cloudera-quickstart-vm

I am trying to find a link to download cloudera zip file on VMWare , but unable to get any.

Tried searching on google , on cloudera website , but in vain.

Can somebody share some views on it.

Comment: Did my answer resolve your query?

Answer (score 1):

Seems Cloudera no longer supports Quickstart VM. I too faced this issue a month ago. I finally found a link to archived version here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nnvheRZYLP4

In the description of the above link, you will find the Google drive [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1sSPNIa1fI7Gt3L8tMqTcSlSNa7_b8zfE/view) for `Cloudera 5.13.0`. That's all i was able to find.

Comment: Thanks for the info. @Technext

Comment: Glad it worked for you. :) You may consider upvoting/marking it as an answer. Kindly go through this link, in case you're not aware how to do it: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 1):

Cloudera indeed no longer provides a quickstart VM for the legacy CDH 5 platform, this can be seen [here](https://docs.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-14-x/topics/cloudera_quickstart_vm.html) as you get redirected to CDP datacenter.

However be aware that CDH 5 relates to a **very** old distribution. I believe CDH 5 goes end of life this year. Even CDH 6 is not recommended for new clusters, as CDP 7 is already GA for a while. CDP, the [Cloudera Data Platform](https://www.cloudera.com/products/cloudera-data-platform.html) is the successor to both CDH and HDP.

If you want to check out the latest version, there is a trial which should serve for most purposes that you may wanted to use the quickstart. This can be downloaded [here](https://docs.cloudera.com/cdp/latest/release-guide/topics/cdpdc-trial-download-information.html).

---

Full disclosure: I am an employee of Cloudera, the company behind both CDH and CDP.